# How to convert a string to type int or float?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, int, string-parsing

I have a problem with putting the value of `creditos` and `nota` in the structure.

I have a file with this, for example:

> Grade: 4.5

I'm using `strtok`, but it returns a char pointer, and I need a `int` and a `float`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
char *nombre;
int creditos;
float nota;
}curso;

int conteo(FILE *_entrada);
void semestre(FILE *_entrada,curso *_materias,int *_cantidad,int *_ganadas,int *_perdidas,float *_promedio);
void imprimir(curso *_materias,int *_cantidad,int *_ganadas, int *_perdidas,float *_promedio);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int ganadas=0;
int perdidas=0;
float promedio=0.0;
int cantidad=0;
char archivoEntrada[256];
curso *materias;
printf("Archivo de entrada \n");
scanf("%255s",archivoEntrada);
FILE *entrada;
entrada=fopen(archivoEntrada,"r");
if(entrada==NULL){
printf("No se logro abrir el archivo de entrada\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

cantidad=conteo(entrada);

materias=(curso *)malloc(sizeof(curso)*cantidad);

semestre(entrada,materias,&cantidad,&ganadas,&perdidas,&promedio);

imprimir(materias,&cantidad,&ganadas,&perdidas,&promedio);

free(materias);
}


int conteo(FILE *_entrada){
int i=0;
char auxiliar[40];
while(!feof(_entrada)){
fgets(auxiliar,40,_entrada);
i++;
}
rewind(_entrada);
return i/3;
}

void semestre(FILE *_entrada,curso *_materias,int *_cantidad,int *_ganadas,int *_perdidas,float *_promedio){
int i=0;
int sumaCreditos=0;
float sumaNotas=0.0;
char auxiliar2[100];
char *token;
fgets(auxiliar2 ,100,_entrada);
while(i<*_cantidad){
fgets(auxiliar2,100,_entrada);
token=strtok(auxiliar2,":");
token=strtok(NULL,":");
printf("Dato: %s \n",token);
(_materias->nombre)=token;

fgets(auxiliar2 ,100,_entrada);
token=strtok(auxiliar2,":");
(&_materias->creditos)=token;
sumaCreditos=sumaCreditos+(_materias->creditos);

fgets(auxiliar2 ,100,_entrada);
token=strtok(auxiliar2,":");
(&_materias->nota)=token;

if((_materias->nota)>3.0){
*_ganadas=(*_ganadas)+1;
}
else{
*_perdidas=(*_perdidas)+1;
}
sumaNotas=sumaNotas+((_materias->nota)*(_materias->creditos));
i++;
*_materias++;
}
*_promedio=(sumaNotas/sumaCreditos);
}

void imprimir(curso *_materias,int *_cantidad,int *_ganadas, int *_perdidas,float *_promedio){
char archivoSalida[256];
FILE *salida;
printf("Archivo de salida \n");
scanf("%255s",archivoSalida);
salida=fopen(archivoSalida,"w");
if(salida==NULL){
printf("No se logro abrir el archivo de salida\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int i=0;
fprintf(salida,"Archivo de Salida: \n");
fprintf(salida,"Materia\tNota\tCreditos \n");
while(i<*_cantidad){
fprintf(salida,"%s\t%f\t%d \n",(_materias->nombre),(_materias->nota),(_materias->creditos));
_materias++;
i++;
}
fprintf(salida,"\nTotal de materias: %d \n",*_cantidad);
fprintf(salida,"Materias ganadas: %d \n",*_ganadas);
fprintf(salida,"Materias perdidas: %d \n",*_perdidas);
fprintf(salida,"Promedio ponderado: %f \n",*_promedio);
}
```

Comment: So you're asking how to convert a string to an int, and how to convert a string to a float?

Comment: Please format your code neatly and preserve the indenting. I started to do it but it looked like there were unbalanced braces and that it wouldn't even compile. Like @immibis asked, can you please narrow down the question and example to the point you specifically need help for?

Comment: its a pointer, from char pointer to float or int

Comment: fgets(auxiliar2 ,100,_entrada);
token=strtok(auxiliar2,":");
(&_materias->nota)=token;                                                                            here is my problem, i need a parsing but i dont know

Comment: [do not cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `token` is a pointer to `char`, which is the same as string in C.

Use `atoi` to convert a string to a `int`:

```
_materias->creditos = atoi(token);
```

Use `atof` to convert a string to a `float`:

```
_materias->nota = atof(token);
```

---

If you need to make your program more robust to errors in your input file, use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) instead. They are harder to use but more secure if your input file can have errors (i.e. always).

---

Alternatively, use `sscanf` - it's probably easier to use than `strtol` and `strtof`, and supports detection of errors, but it has no type safety, so may lead to hard-to-fix frustrating crashes.

Usage:

```
if (sscanf(token, "%d", &_materias->creditos) != 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error\n"); 

if (sscanf(token, "%f", &_materias->nota) != 1)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
```